# Ansible playbook_dir | basename

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I want to remember current playbook folder name and pass it to another imported playbook. I set fact as `"playbook_dir | basename"` that returns proper folder name: **appfolder**. I pass it as **bpm_folder** to the imported playbook it is visible as **appfolder** (debug returns: `"msg": "appfolder"`) but it doesn't work.

Inside imported playbook I got: `skipping vars_file '../{{ bpm_folder }}/deployment_settings.yml' due to an undefined variable.`

But when I add vars to imported playbook ant set "bpm_folder: 'appfolder'" it does work, even if this is exactly the same folder name.

The point is that I want to get the appfolder automatically. How to fix it?

```
---
- name: pre deploy
  hosts: myhosts
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        myfolder: "{{ playbook_dir | basename }}"

- name: start deploy
  import_playbook: '../Common/deploy.yml'
  vars:
    bpm_folder: 'appfolder' <- it is working
    bpm_folder: "{{ myfolder }}" <-- doent't work
```

```
ansible --version
  ansible [core 2.11.6]
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Aug 13 2020, 07:46:32) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]
  jinja version = 3.0.2
  libyaml = True
```

Best regards!

Comment: Are you loading the variables file with `vars_files:` in `deploy.yml` playbook?

Comment: are you using a variable created in a precedent playbook?  what hosts are you using on the playbook deploy.yml?

Answer (score 1):

According your description it seems to be related to [the difference between include_... and import_...](https://serverfault.com/questions/875247/).

Since the import is static and pre-processed at the time playbooks are parsed, the variable isn't initialized at that stage.

Might `import_task: ../Common/deploy.yml` work for you?

Comment: I would rather not change deploy.yml as a task list but I'll try that. The problem is that the fact "myfolder" is visible inside imported playbook because I is showned by debug, so I don't understant why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Artyum because it's templated before executed, but both of these happen after `import`. On the other hand, `include` works during execution, so templating might occur.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow this variable is not getting evaluated under the `vars_file:` section. Since you are able to get the value of `bpm_folder` when doing `debug` (`tasks` section) in  `deploy.yml`, I'd suggest using [include_vars module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/include_vars_module.html) to load the variables.

For example in `deploy.yml`:

```yaml
- hosts: myhosts

  tasks:
    - debug:
         msg: "{{ bpm_folder }}"
    - include_vars:
        file: "../{{ bpm_folder }}/deployment_settings.yml"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason it shouldn't work if the *hosts* are the same in both plays, e.g.

```yaml
shell> cat deploy.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: bpm_folder
```

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_folder: "{{ playbook_dir | basename }}"

- import_playbook: deploy.yml
  vars:
    bpm_folder: "{{ my_folder }}"
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] **********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  bpm_folder: tmp8
```

---

The problem might appear when any host in the imported play is not included in the first play, e.g.

```yaml
shell> cat deploy.yml
- hosts: host1,host2
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: bpm_folder
```

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: host1
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_folder: "{{ playbook_dir | basename }}"

- import_playbook: deploy.yml
  vars:
    bpm_folder: "{{ my_folder }}"
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [host1] => 
  bpm_folder: tmp8
ok: [host2] => 
  bpm_folder: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!
```

---

You can fix it by including all hosts in the first play too. It is enough to run the *set_fact* once, e.g.

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: host1,host2
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_folder: "{{ playbook_dir | basename }}"
      run_once: true

- import_playbook: deploy.yml
  vars:
    bpm_folder: "{{ my_folder }}"
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [host1] => 
  bpm_folder: tmp8
ok: [host2] => 
  bpm_folder: tmp8
```